# Is it possible to force control to an NSWindowController Subclass?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsobject, nswindowcontroller

I am creating a cocoa application and I am loading a preference window with a NSWindowController.

When the user selected the prefs button and the preference window opens

I want the application to force the user to finish what they are doing with the newly opened window controller before going back to the application in the background.

Is there anyway to block out whats happening in the background and force the user to complete there interactions with the foreground?

Thakns

Comment: What you want is called a modal window, which should be avoided if possible. Why do you want to do this? There may be a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Because currently I have a preferences button that makes a HUD window overlay my application and the user can change the font size of the tableview in the background. The problem is that a user still has the ability to edit the textfield in the tableview while they can change the font size in the prefs window. This causes an error in the NSTableView row.

Comment: So I am trying to effectively disable the app when the HUD window is shown

Comment: What is the error? Fixing the error is the solution, not blocking interaction with the user. Please supply more information about the *actual* problem, not the workaround that you think is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this works? Create a subclass of the HUD window and implement

```
- (BOOL)resignFirstResponder {
    if (userMayLeave) return YES;
    return NO; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to achieve this and display your window as a modal:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:aWindow];
```

Then you need to use one of the following methods in your modal window in order to dismiss it:

```
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModal];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] abortModal];
[[NSApplication sharedApplication] stopModalWithCode:anInteger];
```